# Errors in the slider

Tags: javascript, css, animation, button, slider

By the condition slider has to be fixated, and switched by pressing the button. Individually, all works cool, and together - breaks. The situation is this ... When the slider is just starting and the first slide appears, switching the buttons work. But as soon as the animation is done and the first is replaced by a second slide, it stops working. More precisely - if there is a second slide, then pressing the first button should turn first, but it does not work ... and starts to work, only if before this press the second button. Similarly for the other slide ...

```js
  var toggle1 = document.querySelector(".slide-1");
        var toggle2 = document.querySelector(".slide-2");
        var slide1 = document.querySelector(".first");
        var slide2 = document.querySelector(".second");


        toggle1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          //        event.preventDefault();
          //            slide2.classList.add("display-slide-1");
          //            slide1.classList.add("display-slide-2");
          //            slide2.classList.remove("display-slide-2");
          //            slide1.classList.remove("display-slide-1");

          //            slide2.classList.add("display-2");
          //            slide1.classList.add("display-1");


          slide2.classList.add("display-slide-2");
          slide1.classList.add("display-slide-1");

          //            slide2.classList.remove("display-slide-1");
          //            slide1.classList.remove("display-slide-2");
          //            
          //            slide2.classList.remove("display-2");
          //            slide1.classList.remove("display-1");
        });

        toggle2.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          //        event.preventDefault();
          //            slide2.classList.add("display-slide-2");
          //            slide1.classList.add("display-slide-1");
          //            slide2.classList.remove("display-slide-1");
          //            slide1.classList.remove("display-slide-2");

          //            slide2.classList.add("display-1");
          //            slide1.classList.add("display-2");

          slide2.classList.add("display-slide-1");
          slide1.classList.add("display-slide-2");

          //            slide2.classList.remove("display-slide-2");
          //            slide1.classList.remove("display-slide-1");

          //            slide2.classList.remove("display-1");
          //            slide1.classList.remove("display-2");
        });
```

```css
.promo .slider-promo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 620px;
  height: 265px;
  background-color: #f2f6f8;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "CuprumRegular";
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider-promo .slide-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../img/promo-slide-1.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}
.slider-promo .second {
  /* display: none;*/
  background: url(../img/promo-slide-2.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}
.slider-promo .toggle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 35px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 11px;
}
.slider-promo .label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
@keyframes first-animation {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
  }
  40% {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: -620px;
  }
  51% {
    left: -620px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  52% {
    left: 620px;
  }
  90% {
    left: 620px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes second-animation {
  0% {
    left: -620px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
  }
  1% {
    left: 620px;
  }
  40% {
    left: 620px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0;
  }
  90% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -620px;
  }
}
.display-slide-1 {
  animation: first-animation 12s linear infinite;
}
.display-slide-2 {
  animation: second-animation 12s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-promo">
  <div class="slide-item first display-slide-1">
    <div class="name">
      <h3>First slide</h3>
      <span>Lorem lorem lorem</span>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="btn">More info</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item second display-slide-2">
    <div class="name">
      <h3>Second slide</h3>
      <span>Lorem lorem lorem</span>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="btn">More info</a>
  </div>

  <div class="toggle">
    <div class="label slide-1"></div>
    <div class="label slide-2"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

when Click the toggle, In appropriate toggle event stop the animation of both slide by removing the classList from the node element and show the appropriate slide and make delay your need  then  add the animation into node element.

Here i provided logic for show slide2 ,onclick toggle-2

```
toggle2.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
           slide2.classList.remove("display-slide-2");
           slide1.classList.remove("display-slide-1");

         //  alert( slide2.style.zIndex +" "+  slide1.style.zIndex);
           slide1.style.left = "-620px";
           slide2.style.left = "0px";
           slide2.style.zIndex  = "2";
           slide2.style.display ="block";

            setTimeout(function(){
               slide2.classList.add("display-slide-2");
               slide1.classList.add("display-slide-1");
           },1000);  // set delay as per your need

        });

I hope this meet your expectation
```

Comment: Great! It works) Thank you) I tried to do almost the same, about position and display, but maybe did something wrong. But I changed your code a bit: 
           slide2.classList.remove("display-slide-2");
           slide1.classList.remove("display-slide-1");
            slide2.classList.remove("display-slide-1");
           slide1.classList.remove("display-slide-2");
because we don't know which class in which slide... And 
slide2.classList.add("display-slide-1");
slide1.classList.add("display-slide-2");
because when we click on 2button 2slide have to became the start of slider